# What is the volume generated by rotating a solid along a given line?

Tags: calculus

I have a region spanned between $x^2$ and $x$ in the first quadrant. What would be the volume if we rotated it along the line $y=2$. I know how to do it if it was the $x$ axis but not this.

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. You are more likely to get help if you [edit] the question to show us what you tried and where you are stuck. Hint: describe the region in a new coordinate system where you raise the $x$-axis $2$ units.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find the difference between the rotated region of $x^2$ and $x$ and subtract them from each other to get the volume when the figure is between the two curves:

$\pi r^2=\pi (2-x^2)^2 - \pi (2-x)^2=\pi ((2-x^2)^2 -(2-x)^2)$

Now take the integral

$\int_{0}^{1}\pi ((2-x^2)^2 -(2-x)^2) dx$

Answer (score 0):

You may use the cylinder method and integrate $x$ over (0,1) as follows,

$$V=\int_0^1 2\pi r(h_1-h_2)dx=2\pi\int_0^1 (2-x)(x-x^2)dx=\frac\pi2$$

where $r=2-x$.

Comment: @Jay563 - 2 answers give different numerical results